# How to open gallery (not letting the user choose between Gallery to Photo apps)

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried this:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(getIntent, getString(R.string.select_image)), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
```

but it lets me choose which app to open (Gallery/Photo/File Explorer) and I want it to open Gallery.

I also tried this but no success:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for open gallery from app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

OnActivityResult for get image.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)  {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it opens the Downloads and I can navigate to Gallery\Recent\Images and it's not what I wanted. I'm trying it on S10.